# Where does energy go in an induced electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction

The induced electric field is produced due to changing magnetic field field is non-conservative in nature. However this is in contradiction to my prior understanding that all fundamental forces are conservative. Also where does the energy dissipated due to an induced electric field go? Conversation to heat doesn't seem a satisfactory answer

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question very well, but when we say there is a "nonconservative field" it doesn't mean that energy is not conserved in a system of which the field is a part.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Dissipated" energy generally means it was converted to heat, so why is that not a satisfactory explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electric field is always the separation of charge carriers. One side has an excess of electrons, the other a deficiency. In a state of equilibrium, we measure no field because the electric fields of the electrons and protons balance each other out in the atom. Inductive processes such as the movement of electrons through a conductor cause the electrons to be deflected sideways and charge separation occurs (Lorentz force, Hall effects). Then you can measure the electric fields. They were there before, only now they are aggregated and separated.

Something else to think about. The inducing magnetic field is not consumed. It is only a kind of catalyst (i.e. something that is involved in a reaction but is not itself converted). In fact, the kinetic energy of the electrons (of the flowing current) is converted into heat. So any induced lateral deflection is done by electromagnetic radiation.